# Multiple divs sharing same redux State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am building a react widget builder, everything is completed but now I am stuck on this thing that I am running my react app on every **div** which has **data** attribute of **data-widget="custom"** like this code {renderCustomWidget is just the function to render react app}

```
<body>
<div  data-widget="custom" data-id="appName_userToken_timeStamp1" ></div>
<div  data-widget="custom" data-id="appName_userToken_timeStamp2" ></div>
<div  data-widget="custom" data-id="appName_userToken_timeStamp3" ></div>
</body>
```

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
            document.querySelectorAll('div[data-widget="custom"]').forEach(function (element) {
                renderCustomWidget(element)
            });
        }
</script>
```

*the data-id attribute makes each div's content unique*

now I am building multiple widgets by just writing multiple widgets with the **data-widget='custom'** attribute.
But the problem is that as I have only a single universal redux state for the entire application all the divs are showing the same content.

I want a way so that all the divs make their own block of redux state and manage that by only their own app reducers and actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in redux to have multiple state slices, in fast its what is recommended. Have a look at the [docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers/#reducers).

Comment: hey, @daza thanks for the help but now I am stuck that I want to build a widget builder that will be running on a single website and resulting in the formation of unlimited widgets. And each user action and user input is saved in redux state, so how can I distinguish between the actions and inputs of countless widgets on single website as depend upon user?

Comment: @TalhaAbbas Im not so much familiar with with widgets, also how should a use case with "unlimited widgets" look like? Maybe you can describe a specific use case, then it is more clear